# How to open album list like photos native application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

As i saw this in "Viber" application. There is media sharing button which opens all the albums as shown in photos native application. Can we do this ? I found UIImagePickerController cannot shows both simultaneously. How show both photo gallery and video gallery simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about `UIImagePickerController` here great [guide](http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/), and [github](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake) project for picking media.

If you want to share your media here's some cool examples:

Check this [tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/email/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-example-using-iphone-camera-to-email-a-photo.html) on how to share pictures via email.

If you want to share via mail -
First of all you have to Create NSData object from your PNG/JPEG image data and then implement the method: Send `addAttachmentData:mimeType:filename:` to your `MFMailComposeViewController` instance.

Also i think the best thing to use in your case to share stuff like text, pictures etc is [Sharekit](http://getsharekit.com).